# How to search the variables and subroutines in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran

I use Fortran. When I was debugging the codes, I found there is something unconvenient:

For example, the whole code calls ten subroutines which are saved in three different modules. I set breakpoint on the fourth subroutine and the code will stop here, but now, I want go back to see the value of a variable in the third subroutine.

I know the subroutine's name and also the variable's name, but I do not know which module is the subroutine in. What I am confused is: are there any ways to search for the subroutine and variable and open them quickly?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran]. Fortran 90 is just one old version and your problem is not version specific. Please begin your sentences with capital letters, capitalize the word "I" and use paragraphs for better readability.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will pay attention next time. I use Understand to assist the code debugging because this software is really helpful to search the variables and subroutines and also their relationships. However, it will be awesome if VS can do this itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Intel Visual Fortran, which is one of several Fortran compilers that work in Visual Studio, see the topic "Using Source Editor Enhancements in Visual Studio" in the compiler documentation. Specifically, "Enable Find All References" and "Enable Go To Declaration".

You also mention wanting to see values. If these are module variables, you can use the syntax modulename::variablename in the Debugger watch window. If the procedure calls are still active (that is, routine A calls routine B which calls routine C and while in C you want to see what A's local variables are), use the Call Stack control to change the context to that of the calling routine.